# How put userTip at bottom of slider using extjs4.1.3

Tags: extjs, extjs4.1

I am using slider in extjs 4.1.3. I that i am getting userTip at top of slider. Now i want that at bottom of slider code is as follow

```
var slider=Ext.create('Ext.slider.Single', {
  width: 300,
  value: 100,
  increment: 5,
  minValue: 5,
  maxValue: 100,
  labelWidth: 160,
});
```

My slider result is coming like in image as follow:
    [image]

I want as image below
   [image]

Please help me for same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Ext.slider.Tip.prototype.offsets = [0, 50];`

Just add this line above your code. 
This makes all the sliders' **tipText** to come below, no need to mention for each one.

Or if you wan to add only to that slider then use below listener:

```
  listeners:{    
 render:function( ths, eOpts ){      
 ths.plugins[0].offsets = [0,50]; 
      }  
 }
```